# Avoid multiple invoking of windows service using timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

I am working on windows service.I am using timer 15 minutes for service.
What my service do is when started it checks database field according to that field it starts moving images.
Now problem i am facing is once service is started and it started copying images and its taking couple of hour to copy images.. but after 15 min its starting again.

How do I solve this problem. I read that using threads it can be stopped.

```
#region Timer
    public void SetTimer()
    {
        if (_timer != null)
        {
            _timer.Dispose();
            _timer = null;
        }
        _timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(this.RunProcesses), null, 0, interval * 60 * 1000); //  Min  * Sec * Mili Seconds(1000 msec=1sec)

    }
    #endregion

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //WriteMessageInLog("Service  Started at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        if (ReadServiceSettings())
            RunProcesses(true);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (ReadServiceSettings())
        {   
            // log the error using log4net.
            WriteMessageInLog("Service Started at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            SetTimer();
        }
        else
        {
            WriteMessageInLog("Default parameter not set");
            OnStop();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        WriteMessageInLog("Service Stoped at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }



    private void RunProcesses(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Monitor.TryEnter(padlock))
                return;



            WriteMessageInLog("Sync Service Started at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            using (DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext())
            {
                var listOfClients = db.Clients.Select(c => new { c.IDClient, c.MMSLPath });
                foreach (var objclientId in listOfClients)
                {
                   // heavy process which will take around 30-1 hour
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteErrorInLog(ex.Message, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(padlock);
        }
    }
```

What I want that if copying process is running then after 15 minutes .. service won't start again...I guess after 15 minutes it starts new thread.. so i want to stop if its already running

EDIT : I have updated the code . Now I am using Monitor.TryEnter method to check if process is running. I have set frequency of timer 15 minutes.
Now what is when service is started and it started copying process.. after 15 minutes its getting stopped :(.

Can anyone help me why its being stopped after 15 minutes.

Comment: So you don't want to prevent your service to run multiple times (which it can't), you want your timer tick handler `RunProcesses` to run only once at a time?

Comment: What you want to do when timer fires again while you're already doing the work?

Comment: What i want that if copying process is running then after 15 minutes .. service won't start again...I guess after 15 minutes it starts new thread.. so i want to stop if its already running

Comment: @Spenzo, If you want to open your question, you've to update your question with as much information (or the things you've tried so far). Then it may case it will reopen.